# Use my own namespace to extend Mavens pom.xml

Tags: xml, maven, xml-namespaces

I wanted to add my own information to the `pom.xml` and
though I could be clever to just add my own XML-Elements to the document
and just use an own namespace for them.

But Maven doesn't like that, it says it is malformed.

The original `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>my</groupId>
                <artifactId>my-lib</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

And my change adds the `my:`-namespace:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:my="urn:my/mvn-extensions"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <my:jenkins>http://jenkins.example.com/job/my/</my:jenkins>
                <groupId>my</groupId>
                <artifactId>my-lib</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

Is it Maven which can not handle that or is it me  making an error?

Comment: First question why do you need to add something in your pom file? What kind of problem are you trying to solve? And short answer to that is: No you can not change the pom.xml file ... To add a dependency you don't need to change the pom at all?

Comment: Please describe what exact kind of problem you are trying to solve... I don't understand your intention ? Why do you like to change the pom file? What kind of information etc? please become specific.... I assume those kind of problems have already being solved... ?

Comment: @khmarbaise We have a parent pom with a list of our own dependencies. When a dependency needs to be updated it would be convenient to have a link to the lokal gitlab and the jenkins pipeline. The maintainer of the parent pom would then have a convenient place to trigger a build/release.

Comment: First having dependencies in your parent is the wrong way better using a BOM instead. In a parent there should only being plugins + configuration configured... Upgrades should be handled via renovate/dependabot or alike (or even self implemented solutions) ...which will create a branch and builds automatically (maybe weekly triggered on Jenkins weekley) ... also for the current project... also POM's have already entries for https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#continuous-integration-management

Comment: @khmarbaise Many good tips there, thanks, I will look into dependabot etc. Also I didn't know about 'ciManagement', interesting, but not what I mean. But: As you can see I _am_ talking about a parent-pom with "dependencyManagement/dependency" declarations, not the dependencies itself; it's about having a common place for declaring the versions. Still, our ci/cd (Jenkins) is set up and having a place in the src that links to the jenkins pipeline would be useful. May fallback option will be to generate the pom.xml from a document with all the info. An excel sheet ;-) (no, not really) !

Comment: @khmarbaise I looked at renovate and dependabot and all very good and interesting, but the part of updating the pom is already solved internally.

Comment: Based on GroupId/ArtifactId/Version you can get the appropriate pom, and in that pom is the correct information located. So I have understood very well that you want to go from the current project via parent to the depMgmt ... also each project should be upgrading via automatic tools in these days (triggered each week..)....A common place for dependencies is a BOM file not the parent of a project in general (prefer composition over inheritance).. that means the BOM is the composition part...